# IE11 performance.now() returns Infinity

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I've identified a bug where the `performance.now()` API's for IE 11 return `Infinity`. I've noticed this only happens when the following registry key is set:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"TabProcGrowth"=dword:00000000
```

I've repro'd this on Win10 and Server 2016. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `performance.now()` with your own function based on `Date.now()`. You lose the benefits of the API (such as sub-millisecond precision and the monotonically increasing clock) but code that depends on `performance.now()` should be indifferent to the change.

```
// Run this as early as possible for the most accurate start time
(function() {
  if(!isFinite(performance.now())) {
    var start = Date.now();
    performance.now = function() { return Date.now() - start; }
  }
})();
```